# How this is duplicate?

Tags: discussion

How this question [How to create a reliable natural integral operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-create-a-reliable-natural-integral-operator) a duplicate of this one [Under what conditions does Mathematica give a natural antiderivative when integrating?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58011/under-what-conditions-does-mathematica-give-a-natural-antiderivative-when-integr) ?

The older question asks about Mathematica's behavior, the later one asks how to construct a function. How they can be duplicates if they ask different things?

Comment: Note that on MMA.SE, the following can play a role in closing. (1) The likelihood that a question will receive an answer and (2) the desirability that more time will be spent on the question can be factors in closing. This may be different to what you are used to on other SE subsites.

Comment: Probably because they looked too similar when it got into the review queue. This happens. To me there is also a significant difference between [extracting the probability density function from `SmoothHistogram`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58843/18476) and [exporting SmoothHistogram plot data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38012/18476). But there is the reopen vote to correct the situation, when the difference between the two questions got clarified.